# Select first letter from firstname only

Tags: php, mysql

I have been battling with this for a while now can anyone offer a solution to this.
I want to only show results where the first letter of firstname is "blah".

```
$n=$_GET['n']; 

("SELECT * FROM my_list 
                    WHERE setid = '16-17'
                    and firstname like '$n%' 
                    order by studentid asc")
```

The above is what is have so far but shows no results at all.

thanks all

Comment: There's literally nothing... Would you like to tell us what's the row result and what is expected from it?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: think of   /index.php?n=' OR 1=1 OR '  . It is called sql injection. escape your input or use prepared statements

Comment: "blah" is a word, not a letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $n = $_GET['n']; 

    $value = $n[0]; // will give first letter

    ("SELECT * FROM my_list WHERE setid = '16-17'and
firstname like '". $value ."%' order by studentid asc")
```

Comment: Hi all, all the above examples seem to work but I am still getting no results.I am putting your examples straight in to phpmyadmin sql and running it direct and nothing returns in the results. could my MySQL be at fault now ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use mysql's [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to get the first character.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM my_list 
WHERE
  setid = '16-17'
  AND LEFT(firstname, 1) = 'x' 
ORDER BY
  studentid ASC
```

Will return all firstnames starting with x.